# Weld using alternative producer from src/test/META-INF/beans.xml

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld, weld, weld-se

I am trying to use Weld SE 2.3.0.Final to swap an alternative implementation of an injected dependency during testing by supplying a different `beans.xml` in `src/test/resources/META-INF`

It always seems to use the main version of `beans.xml` though and I'm not sure why.

First of all here are the supporting classes

Engine.java

```
public interface Engine
{
    void start();
    void stop();
}
```

DefaultEngine.java

```
@Vetoed
public class DefaultEngine implements Engine
{

    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Cough cough vrummmmm");
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        System.out.println("Phhhut clank");
    }

}
```

Car.java

```
public class Car
{
    @Inject
    private Engine engine;

    public void startCar()
    {
        engine.start();
    }

    public void stopCar()
    {
        engine.stop();
    }

}
```

EngineProducer.java

```
public class EngineProducer
{

    @Produces
    public Engine getEngine()
    {
        return new DefaultEngine();
    }

}
```

App.java

```
public class App 
{
    @Inject
    private Car car;

    public void main(@Observes ContainerInitialized event)
    {
        car.startCar();
        car.stopCar();
    }
}
```

And the production version of `beans.xml` in `src/main/resources/META-INF`

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

The above code when run from App.java should print (and it does)

```
Cough cough vrummmmm
Phhhut clank
```

Now from the test code I want to use the `SportsEngine` implementation. So I have the following

SportsEngine.java

```
@Vetoed
public class SportsEngine implements Engine
{

    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Vrummm vrummm vrummmm!");
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        System.out.println("Prrrrrr clunk");
    }

}
```

TestEngineProducer.java

```
@Alternative
public class TestEngineProducer
{

    @Produces
    public Engine getEngine()
    {
        return new SportsEngine();
    }

}
```

AppTest.java

```
@RunWith(WeldJUnit4Runner.class)
public class AppTest
{

    @Inject
    private Car car;

    @Test
    public void testCar()
    {
        car.startCar();
        car.stopCar();
    }

}
```

WeldJUnit4Runner.java

```
public class WeldJUnit4Runner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner
{

    /** The test class to run. */
    private final Class<?> mKlass;
    /** Weld infrastructure. */
    private final Weld weld;
    /** The container itself. */
    private final WeldContainer container;

    /**
     * Runs the class passed as a parameter within the container.
     * 
     * @param klass
     *            to run
     * @throws InitializationError
     *             if anything goes wrong.
     */
    public WeldJUnit4Runner(final Class<Object> klass) throws InitializationError
    {
        super(klass);
        this.mKlass = klass;
        this.weld = new Weld();
        this.container = weld.initialize();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createTest() throws Exception
    {
        final Object test = container.instance().select(mKlass).get();
        return test;
    }
}
```

And the test version of `beans.xml` in `src/test/resources/META-INF`

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <alternatives>
        <class>com.test.testing.TestEngineProducer</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

When the test method is run it should print

```
Vrummm vrummm vrummmm!
Prrrrrr clunk
```

But instead it seems to use the `EngineProducer` instead of the `TestEngineProducer` and prints the output twice

```
Cough cough vrummmmm
Phhhut clank
Cough cough vrummmmm
Phhhut clank
```

Why is it not using the test beans.xml?

If I put the `<alternatives>` section from test beans.xml and put it in the main beans.xml then it works, but I don't want to swap the beans.xml in main/resources/META-INF when I'm testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a bug of Weld Se. It only use beans.xml version under src/main/resources/META-INF.

The solution is using beans.xml under CDI-SE src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml for test purpose and you may need to add < exclude> into beans.xml too.

You can have another production beans.xml file and when you export your code into deployment package (jar, war, ear). Don't forget to replace your testing beans.xml by your production beans.xml.

If you are developing web app. You can create your production beans.xml under WEB-INF. 2 version of beans.xml exists but only WEB-INF/beans.xml is used by WAS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <scan>
        <exclude name="org.jboss.weld.**" />
        <exclude name="com.your_package.EngineProducer" />
    </scan>
    <alternatives>
        <class>com.test.testing.TestEngineProducer</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

Comment: Just try it and let me know the result!

Comment: I have same result :(

Comment: Please move test/resources/META-INF/beans.xml to src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml --- It should work

Comment: Well yes I did try putting the `<alternatives>` section in the main version of beans.xml and that does indeed inject the `SportsEngine` but I want to use the test version of beans.xml

Comment: The reason is Weld Se only use beans.xml version in src/main/resources when you run jUnit test

Comment: Hmmm that may fix test code, but what happens for production code, won't the EngineProducer always be ignored? BTW this is a desktop app

Comment: You can create another actual beans.xml and when you export your app to Jar file, you need to replace the testing beans.xml by your actual beans.xml. Just one more step.